# OpenSSL SSL_read return fragments

Tags: openssl

using SSL_read form my application , client is sending data of 561 byte(un-encrypted, found by adding private key in wireshark) , but my app is receiving data of 1 bytes, on wireshark I see that data is sent in 2 SSL segments of 1 bytes and 560 bytes(but they are in same packet ).
Why openssl layer at my app end is not joining both the segments and return just 1 segment of 561

Is their any settings in openssl to enable re-assembly of segments ?

Comment: The `read` function returns when OpenSSL has data. If its an incomplete SSL record, then OpenSSL will return -1 with `SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ`. If OpenSSL gets a full record, then it will return whatever data was encapsulated in the SSL record. Its up to your app to reassemble the partial data. Some related functions that may help: `BIO_set_read_buffer_size` and `BIO_set_write_buffer_size`. And also see [Optimizing NGINX TLS Time To First Byte (TTTFB)](http://www.igvita.com/2013/12/16/optimizing-nginx-tls-time-to-first-byte/).